# The app references non-public selectors in Payload: hidden

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

I get this error when [Validating...] the iOS App in Xcode Organizer:

`The app references non-public selectors in Payload/name.app/scheme: hidden`.

However, `hidden` is a public property defined in UIView.h as:

> @property(nonatomic,getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;

What can cause the invocation of a public selector to fail Apple App Store validation?

Answer (score 1):

**In short**

Replaced:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(hidden))
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:nil];
```

by:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"hidden"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:nil];
```

**In details**

In following [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) on KVO (Key-Value Observing), I used `NSStringFromSelector(@selector(hidden))` for key path since, in truth, "*...any typo or misspelling won't be caught by the compiler, and will cause things to not work.*"

As it turns out, the `hidden` property has an explicit getter, which is different from the property name:

`@property(nonatomic,getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;`

I verified this with the `opaque` property as well.

`@property(nonatomic,getter=isOpaque) BOOL opaque;`

It too fails validation:
**The app references non-public selectors in Payload/*name*.app/*scheme*: opaque.**